# Prove $\gcd(a^m - 1, a^n - 1)=a^{\gcd(m,n)} - 1$ for any natural number $a>1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ideals, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n$, $m$ - natural numbers, at least one $>0$. Let $a$ - natural number $>1$.
Prove 
$\gcd(a^m - 1, a^n - 1)=a^{\gcd(m,n)} - 1$.

It is probably easy, but I cant catch it. I thought abut treating these guys as polynomials of variable "$a$". Looking that way, I know that $a^d-1$ divides $a^n - 1$ (both treated as polynomials) if and only if $d$ divides $n$. Therefore, I see that guy on the right divides guys on the left.
But how I can it is the biggest common divisor?
I don't see it.
Looking from the ideal point of view is also pointless. That exercise does not have hint at the end of book I'm working with.
Thanks in advance for help and Merry Christmas.

Comment: Can you show that if $m>n$ then $\gcd(a^m-1,a^n-1)=\gcd(a^{m-n}-1,a^n-1)$?

Comment: iterate the process $a(a^n-1)+(a-1)$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown At that moment I can't :( But I understand it is enough - by induction on $m$ with $n$ constant; here You reduce $m$ to $m-n$ which is smaller.

Comment: Correct (+1). Following that line of thinking you can basically switch the running of Euclid's algorithm to the exponents :-)